# Are there multiple ways to complete a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Given sequence F as described:
$$F=\{\frac{0}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{4}{5}, \frac{6}{w}, \frac{8}{11}, \frac{10}{13}, \ldots\}$$
The value of $w$ would be $7$ because all divisors are prime numbers.
($F_i = \frac{i-1}{p_i}$ where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime)

But I would like to know if $8$ could be a possible value for $w$ because of these reasons:

We split $F$ into subsequences $G = \{F_1, F_3, F_5, \ldots\}$ and $H = \{F_2, F_4, \ldots\}$
Then $G$ satisfies
$$G_i = \frac{4i}{3^i+2}\\
G = \{\frac{0}{2}, \frac{4}{5}, \frac{8}{11}, \frac{12}{29}, \ldots\}$$
Another valid formula would be $G_i = \frac{4i}{q_{i-1}+3i}$ where $q_i$ denotes the denominator of $G_i$. This would yield
$$G = \{\frac{0}{2}, \frac{4}{5}, \frac{8}{11}, \frac{12}{20}, \ldots\}$$
$H$ satisfies
$$H_i = \frac{4i+2}{r_{i-1}+5}$$
where $r_i$ is the denominator of $H_i$.
$$H = \{\frac{2}{3}, \frac{6}{8}, \frac{10}{13}, \frac{14}{18}\}$$
So, not minding complexity, **can we accept both $7$ and $8$ as possible values for $w$?**
Or is the described derivation unacceptable as proof for that and why?

Comment: not clear to read !

Comment: You could provide a better feedback as why is it not clear to read and how could I improve it.

Comment: Use latex, see here for a tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you very much @Mattos :) I will try to redo it in a few minutes.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it can be any value you like. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation. Of course when asked this kind of question, it is implied that we want to find a simple formula. "Simple" is subjective, but most who know about primes would disagree that your alternative is simpler than primes. So there is no right or wrong answer unless the criteria for the answer is precisely spelt out. The word "simple" is totally imprecise by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @user21820 I will finish to edit it and I will add that it doesn't mind if its the simpler way or a more complex way. Its just about if there are multiple answers.

Comment: Then there are infinitely many answers, since for any desired value we can find some function that obeys the given terms as well as the desired value of that unknown term, just by simply interpolating through all of them including the desired term.

Comment: I have edited it to be better readable, please do give a feedback if I can improve it.

Comment: @user21820 you should then post it as the answer.

Comment: Frankly, we've seen too many such questions here. For $\times$ use `$\times$` rather than `$x$`.

Comment: So many people put on hold but none of then gave a hint as how to improve it. Also, user21820 understood it perfectly fine. Can any of those who placed it on hold give a hint as why is it not clear?

Comment: Also, @user21820, could you place your answer please? As it answered my question.

Comment: @Pfeiffer Let me summarize why this question was put on-hold: 1. The question is ill-posed: You can find a generating function for _any_ sequence of numbers, so there is no "correct" value for $W$, just one that _might seem more natural to some_.

Comment: 2. The format of the question is very long (in terms of vertical space) although the actual information could be shortened a lot. This makes reading the question and finding out what might actually be a _useful_ answer more difficult. This issue can be partly corrected by making the formatting less torn-apart and partly by removing unnecessary parts from the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. Can you tell me what would be unnecessary parts of it so I can remove an re-do it? I have an idea to make it fit better but I will await your next insight to do it.

Comment: @Pfeiffer I have decided to do a rather radical overhaul of your question in the hope that this will be more helpful to you. First off, I removed a lot of fillers and introduced proper mathematical notation. Secondly I removed the list formatting because it just eats horizontal space with no benefit whatsoever (in this situation). Then I omitted some repetitions wich just make the post longer and push the actual question further down.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was really productive and made me understand why some would find it unclear. Your help was priceless.

Comment: As noted, this kind of question has come up, many times, already. Look at some of the questions listed on this page under the heading "Related" and you may see the ideas that have been put forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a proof needs to show exactly what it claims. In this case, to claim that a particular single value is the answer, it means also to claim that no other value is an answer. So an example that demonstrates one formula that gives $8$ as an answer does not at all exclude the possibility of other formulae that give different answers. Hence there is no proof. For such questions, in fact, there can be no such thing as a proof of the answer, even if everyone accepts the answer. There can however be proof of the weaker claim that there is a formula that has the given terms and gives a certain value at the desired position, which is just to show the formula and prove that it does so, but such proofs won't privilege the value given by the formula since it does not say anything about other values. My original answer in the comments and more details are as follows.

Strictly speaking, it can be any value you like by using any interpolating method. Of course when asked this kind of question, it is implied that we want to find a simple formula. "Simple" is subjective, but most who know about primes would disagree that your alternative is simpler than primes. So there is no right or wrong answer unless the criteria for the answer is precisely spelt out.

Specifically, if you want a certain value as the answer, you just need to interpolate through all the given points as well as the desired point, and there are in fact infinitely many functions that would work. For example, if you want a polynomial to go through $n$ points, there is exactly one polynomial of degree $n-1$ that does, and infinitely many polynomials of degree $n$ that does. And polynomials are just a small class of functions. The obvious "answer" to the sequence you gave uses the function that returns the $n$ prime given input $n$, which is not at all a polynomial.

In case you are wondering, it is actually possible to precisely specify "simple". For example one could say that the simplicity of a function on natural numbers is its Kolmogorov complexity, which you might find interesting to read about. But there are two issues with that. Firstly, it is overdoing it for such questions where there is one obvious "simple answer". Secondly, Kolmogorov complexity and other universal complexity measures in general are uncomputable, meaning that you cannot systematically determine an arbitrary object's complexity, not to say find a description that corresponds to the complexity. One may be able to do it for extremely small cases but not in general.

Incidentally, under any reasonable definition of complexity, the sequence you give will probably not be long enough for the sequence of primes to be the simplest answer! For example, one could argue that the answer could be $10$, by repeating $(2,3,5)$ each time increased by $8$. This is almost surely going to be simpler than the full definition of primes, so the prime sequence would lose out unless it is specially privileged (which happens to be the case in a mathematician's mind). Furthermore, I would guess that you need about 50 terms to be reasonably certain (but almost surely unable to prove) that the prime sequence is the simplest, because it needs to be simpler than just repeating the entire given sequence!

Comment: @Pfeiffer: Here it is with more details. I hope it helps you understand why usually we have insufficient evidence to even support one value over another!

Comment: Thank you very much. I will vote it up when my reputation reach 15.